# Clear List in Session Object

Tags: vb.net

Im very new to Vb..

I get the Following error 'Option Strict On disallows late Binding' when I try to clear a list in my seesionObject like shown.

```
Private Sub ClearSessionList()
    Dim context As Object = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("MySessionobject")
    context.MyListProperty = New List(Of String)
End Sub
```

The error persist when i try following casts aswell

```
DirectCast(context.MyListProperty, List(Of String))
CType(context.MyListProperty, List(Of String))
```

I assume my Casts are wrong in some way, anyone that can point out the error for me and show how I can clear the List?

Comment: What is the type of the object are you storing in the session? You need to use Ctype on the context-object when reading that from the session, that way you get real type for your variable and it's strongly typed code.

Comment: CType(context, MySessionObject).MyPropertyListList = New List(Of String).. This aproach give me an nullpointer aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use [option strict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx), then you couldn't access `MyListProperty` until you haven't casted `context` from `Object` to it's actual type. Otherwise VB.NET will try to cast it for you, sometimes with weird results.

So presuming the type of it is `MySessionObject`:

```
Dim context As Object = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("MySessionobject")
Dim myObj As MySessionObject = DirectCast(context, MySessionObject)
myObj.MyListProperty.Clear()
```

Comment: I get an nullpointer now with this approach on the second line.
The type would be "MySessionObject" as in line 1

Comment: @user3116167: if you get a `NullReferenceException` you haven't added this object to the session before.

Comment: It should be there but atleast i got beyond the initial question :)
Will try and do some debugging on it..